# SQLIte how to insert unique data on change of column value

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am using SQLite Database for my application. I have 4 columns-  Student_Name,Student_Enroll, Student_Mob, Student_Address in my database. Now I can add new record if and only if one of four column value is different or all values are different. If all column values are same then no new record should be generated.
Can you please guide me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enforce that a set of columns must be unique, add a UNIQUE constraint:

```
create table Students (
 /* ID              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, */
    Student_Name    TEXT,
    Student_Enroll  TEXT,
    Student_Mob     TEXT,
    Student_Address TEXT,
    UNIQUE (Student_Name, Student_Enroll, Student_Mob, Student_Address)
);
```

This allows new rows only if at least one of the four columns has a different value.

With a plain INSERT, attempting to insert a duplicate row will result in an error. If you simply want to ignore it instead, use INSERT OR IGNORE:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Students ...;
```

Answer (score 3):

Despite of set your column as UNIQUE you also need to resolve the conflict created on each column when you try to insert new data.

To do so, define the behavior to solve the conflict:

```
"CREATE TABLE table (your columns here...(UNIQUE unique colums here...) ON CONFLICT REPLACE);"
```

Answer (score 0):

During Create Database line insert UNIQUE ...for each column to insert only unique record.

Comment: I set UNIQUE to all my columns. Now I am going to change only 4th column, and rest columns will remains same. Can you please tell me, new record will be inserted or not? As per my requirement, new record should insert.

Comment: Unique helps to store only fresh record. if same data found then it will be neglected

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** (Simple)

Define all columns as `unique`:

```
create table TableName (id  integer primary key autoincrement,
Student_Name text not null unique, 
Student_Enroll text not null unique, 
Student_Mob text not null unique);
```

You can add `Student_Address` as well, if you need to

**Solution 2:** (bit complex)

Use `AND` Operator with `WHERE` clause

```
INSERT INTO TableName (Student_Name, Student_Enroll, Student_Mob)
SELECT varStudentName, varStudentEnroll, varStudentMob 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableName WHERE Student_Name = varStudentName OR Student_Enroll = varStudentEnroll OR Student_Mob = varStudentMob ); 

//If a record already contains a row, then the insert operation will be ignored.
```

You can find more information at [the sqlite manual](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#constraints).

**Live Example:**

1. Open [SQLite Online](https://sqliteonline.com/)
2. Paste following code:

   ```
   INSERT INTO demo (id,name,hint)
   SELECT 4, 'jQuery', 'is a cross-platform JavaScript library designed to simplify the client-side scripting of HTML' 
   WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM demo WHERE name = 'jQuery' OR hint = 'is a cross-platform JavaScript library designed to simplify the client-side scripting of HTML' ); 

   SELECT * from demo
   ```
3. Hit **RUN**

This won't insert 4th record and if you modify both values of `WHERE` clause then record will be inserted.

Comment: The second is not valid SQL.

Comment: please correct the issue OR at least highlight so I can fix it

Comment: You cannot put a WHERE clause after VALUES (see the [manual](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)).

Comment: thanks for pointing out @CL, I have updated answer with live example.